A nabla and surface integral transformation in Landau's book
I am reading Landau & Lifshitz's The Classical Theory of Fields. On page 182, in the solution to problem 1, the authors used a transformation:$$\int \nabla\cdot(\varphi\nabla\varphi)\mathbf rdV=\int(d\mathbf f\cdot\nabla\frac{\varphi^2}{2})\mathbf r-\int\nabla\frac{\varphi^2}{2}dV.$$Here $d\mathbf f$ is the surface element. I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help?

hint: write $\mathbf r = x \mathbf i +y \mathbf  j +z \mathbf k$ and proceed to prove the equality component-wise

It's possible to prove it using integration by parts and divergence theorem (Gauss' lemma, Stokes' theorem, or how you want to all it). I'm using (Cartesian) components notation to make algebra easier to understand, so that
$$\int_V \nabla \cdot (\varphi \nabla \varphi) \mathbf{r} = \int_V (\varphi \varphi_{/j})_{/j} r_k \ .$$
The integrand can be recast as
$$(\varphi \varphi_{/j})_{/j} r_k = \left( \varphi \varphi_{/j} r_k\right)_{/j} - \varphi \varphi_{/j} \underbrace{r_{k/j}}_{\delta_{jk}} \ , \hspace{30pt} (*) $$
and it's easy to prove that $\varphi \varphi_{/j} = \left(\frac{\varphi^2}{2} \right)_{/j} = \nabla \frac{\varphi^2}{2}$. It readily follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_V \nabla \cdot (\varphi \nabla \varphi) \mathbf{r} & = \int_V (\varphi \varphi_{/j})_{/j} r_k =  & (*)\\
& = \int_V \left( \varphi \varphi_{/j} r_k\right)_{/j} - \int_V \varphi \varphi_{/k} = & \left(\int_V  a_{/j} = \oint_{\partial V} a \, n_j \, \right) \\
& = \oint_{\partial V} n_j \left( \frac{\varphi^2}{2} \right)_{/j } r_k - \int_V \left(\frac{\varphi^2}{2}\right)_{/k} = & (\text{back to abstract notation})\\
& = \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \frac{\varphi^2}{2} \, \mathbf{r} - \int_V \nabla \frac{\varphi^2}{2} \ .
\end{aligned}$$
If you explicitly write the elementary volume and surfaces in the integrals, and call $d\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} dS$ the oriented-surface, you immediately get the desired expression.
